# What's wrong with my SVG - it won't fill with a linear gradient?

Tags: svg

I have an SVG (below), but no matter what I try, I cannot the rect shape to fill with the gradient. If I give a direct fill of 'red', it works. When I use my class and fill, nothing shows up and the shape disappears. Any ideas? I've tried inline fill, using a class, all sorts. Really got me stuck. Where it says”path values” I’ve just obfuscated them in the code snippet.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="50px" height="50px" viewBox="0 0 50 50" version="1.1" title="">
   <defs>
      <style>.aHAygrlYwO-fill{fill:url(#aHAygrlYwO)!important;}</style>
      <path d="PATH_VALUES" id="path-1" />
      <lineargradient id="aHAygrlYwO">
         <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color: rgb(187, 188, 175);" />
         <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color: rgb(117, 119, 99);" />
      </lineargradient>
   </defs>
   <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
      <g id="Blockquote/Default">
         <g id="Icon/Text/Style/Blockquote/Default">
            <mask id="mask-2" fill="white">
               <use xlink:href="#path-1" />
            </mask>
            <use fill-rule="evenodd" xlink:href="#path-1" />
            <g id="Color/Solid/Black_#000000" mask="url(#mask-2)">
               <rect class="aHAygrlYwO-fill" id="Black_#000000" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50" style="&#xA;    /* fill: red; */&#xA;" />
            </g>
         </g>
      </g>
   </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: SVG is case sensitive and it's linear**G**radient

Comment: @RobertLongson already tried it, no difference. I actually tried editing an svg with a gradient that works and lineargradient does actually work.

Comment: HTML is not case sensitive so it would only work if you embed your SVG in HTML.

Comment: @RobertLongson As I said, when loading the svg directly in chrome and trying linearGradient, there’s no difference, still doesn’t work.

Comment: Yes it does, I took your code (removed the invalid mask as you've not posted the path d attribute) and the gradient works perfectly well.

Comment: @RobertLongson I already tried camel case directly on the svg in chrome (not in html) and still doesn’t work

Comment: @RobertLongson can you grab a screenshot? I literally tried that and it doesn’t work for me in chrome

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212393/discussion-between-robert-longson-and-fl0shizzle).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Rob Longson's comment, the solution was the case of the element.